# Splitting node.js class extensions between files

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I am trying to make a discord bot in node.js. I have a main file, bot.js, which contains the main control flow. I would like to implement the state of the world as a class and split the actions on that class into other files. However, I'm not really sure how to do this, particularly the part where I have to recombine multiple files of functions (let's call them startup.js and bios.js) that extend the same class.

Should I have a separate file that includes the class definition so that I can import that into both of the helper files?

common.js

```js
module.exports = botState;

class botState {
    //class definition goes here
}
```

initialize.js

```js
const common = require('./common');

class initializeState extends botState {
    constructor () {
        //it's a constructor; details not too important
    }

    function1 () {} //implementation not important

    function2 () {}
}

module.exports = initializeState;
```

chars.js

```js
const common = require('./common');

class bioState extends botState {
    constructor () {
        //it's a constructor; details not too important
    }

    function3 () {} //implementation not important

    function4 () {}
}

module.exports = BioState;
```

bot.js

```js
//main control flow is in this file
//I'd like to have a class that implements functions 1 through 4, but don't know how to do that.
```

I'm not sure how to implement bot.js. There might be some better construction for this entirely.

Comment: Generally you want a class to be in a single file which you can export. Depending on the size of the class, you might put subclasses in the same file, or you can write them in separate files, importing the parent class in each one.

Comment: The main challenge is figuring out how to recombine all the methods, unless I nest all the classes (which I'd rather not do if I can help it). Do you know of any examples to look at?

Comment: Can you post your code? It sounds like there might be a cleaner way to approach your issue but it's hard to tell without seeing what you are working with.

Comment: Code posted! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused by.  In bot.js, you `require()` `chars.js` and `initialize.js` which will give you access to the `bioState` and `initializeState` classes.  If you also want access to make `botState` instances by themself, then you `require()` `initialize.js` too.  Keep in mind that in Javascript, ALL you need to use a class is access to the constructor for the actual class you're calling `new` on.

Comment: The problem is that I want a single class that I can run all four functions on. Is it best to just make a new class and define the methods in terms of the other classes? Or is there some way to inherit all the functions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do some multiple inheritance, which isn't supported in Javascript (see the last section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model), either in the same file or in different files.

That said, what you *can* do is take advantage of how the prototyping system works. You can write functions 1-4 separately from the class definitions, and attach them to the prototypes of the classes you want.

```js
function function1(){
  this.someValue = this.someOtherValue + this.someMethod();
  return 7;
}
// ... and other functions

BioState.prototype.function1 = function1;
InitializeState.prototype.function1 = function1;
```

It doesn't matter where these are defined or attached to the class prototypes -- though for clarity's sake it would make sense to declare the functions in one place, import them to the file for each class that needs it, and attach them to the prototype before you export the class.

```js
const { function1, function2 } = require('./common-functions');
class Blah {
//...
}
Blah.prototype.function1 = function1;
Blah.prototype.function2 = function2;
// You could also do this in the constructor as this.function1 = function1;

module.exports = Blah;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, which file is supposed to be the main file? Are there multiple "tiers" of helper files, or just one?

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter, files can export more than one thing so you can structure it how you like.

Comment: I don't understand which of the two example code blocks is supposed to be in one of the helper files and which was supposed to be in bot.js. I also don't actually need the helper classes BioState and InitializeState.